# Entity Framework Code First Not Pulling Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a problem with a navigation property not being loaded.  I have this same setup with all my other entities, but this is using a property that isnt a natural FK (Number) and wont cascade, that will be handled by a trigger.

```
Expression<Func<DivisionBracketGameParticipant, object>>[] includes2 = {
                                                                                       q => q.DivisionWinnerBracketGame,
                                                                                       q => q.DivisionLoserBracketGame
                                                                                   };
            var test = _divisionBracketGameParticipantsRepository.GetMany(includes2,
                                                                      q =>
                                                                      q.DivisionBracketGame.DivisionBracket.Division.
                                                                          EventId == eventId);
```

**Database Schema**

```
DivisionBracketGame

Id
Number

DivisionBracketGameParticipant

Id
DivisionBracketGameId -> Id
DivisionBracketGameWinnerNumber -> Number
DivisionBracketGameLoserNumber -> Number
```

**Entities**

```
[Table("DivisionBracketGame", Schema = "GrassrootsHoops")]
    public class DivisionBracketGame : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("DivisionBracketGame")]
        public virtual ICollection<DivisionBracketGameParticipant> DivisionBracketGameParticipants { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("DivisionWinnerBracketGame")]
        public virtual ICollection<DivisionBracketGameParticipant> DivisionWinnerBracketGameParticipants { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("DivisionLoserBracketGame")]
        public virtual ICollection<DivisionBracketGameParticipant> DivisionLoserBracketGameParticipants { get; set; }
    }

[Table("DivisionBracketGameParticipant", Schema = "GrassrootsHoops")]
public class DivisionBracketGameParticipant : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual int DivisionBracketGameId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? DivisionWinnerBracketGameNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual int? DivisionLoserBracketGameNumber { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DivisionBracketGameId")]
        public virtual DivisionBracketGame DivisionBracketGame { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DivisionWinnerBracketGameNumber")]
        public virtual DivisionBracketGame DivisionWinnerBracketGame { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DivisionLoserBracketGameNumber")]
        public virtual DivisionBracketGame DivisionLoserBracketGame { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EF will not create relation to `Number` because it is not a primary key. Primary key is of your `DivisionBracketGame` is `Id` so both `DivisionWinnerBracketGame` and `DivisionLoserBracketGame` are targeting `Id` (not `Number`).

One-to-many relation demands that column in principal table is unique - in your case the column should be a `Number`. This is possible in database by either using primary key from principal table or by using unique index on that column. EF doesn't support unique indexes / candidate keys so the only way to build one-to-many relation in EF is through primary key of principal table.

The FK value is used to get related value so at the moment it probably looks for records with wrong value because it uses a wrong column.

Comment: Even if I am explicitly tell it what the foreign key is?

Comment: You can tell EF what property is foreign key for navigation property but you cannot tell EF that the relation is not defined against primary key in principal table.

Comment: Ladislav, can I infer from your statements that navigation properties will be generated **only** for foreign keys that point to primary keys, as opposed to unique keys ? I ask this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327153/are-navigation-properties-generated-only-for-fks-on-pks-as-opposed-to-unique-ke).